# How do i receive DMARC reports with external domains that i have no permission to control

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf, dkim, dmarc

I want to receive reports with gmail or outlook or anything else that i have no permission to add `(mydomain.com)._report._dmarc.(gmail|outlook).com` as a record. What i can do?
Example just like:

```
v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:someone@gmail.com; ruf=someone@gmail.com; fo=1; aspf=s;
```

Then i as it must be have no permission to add an txt record for `gmail.com`.

PS: I know i can just set my record as this without really set for `gmail.com`, then google will continue reports dmarc, without any issue, but mxtoolbox always reporting with `DMARC External Validation Error`, it must be **against the RFC**. So i am asking this.

Comment: It is the sender of the reports that will be in violation of the RFC when it sends to recipients in the `rua` or `ruf` tag, without verifying if indeed the receiving domain allows reports on behalf of the domain being reported on.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, as explained in [RFC 7489, 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489.html#section-7.1):

> Without checks, this would allow a bad actor to publish a DMARC
> policy record that requests that reports be sent to a victim address,
> and then send a large volume of mail that will fail both DKIM and SPF
> checks to a wide variety of destinations; the victim will in turn be
> flooded with unwanted reports.  Therefore, a verification mechanism
> is included.

You could request the reports to an email address within the same domain or another domain you can control. Then, you could forward the reports to Gmail, acknowledging that the forwarded mail might not pass DMARC without a DKIM signature.

Comment: Unforutnately, not many reporting servers check for this permission. Also, the RFC is using vague terms like 'are to be' and 'is enacted', instead of using the proper terminoligy as describedi n the KEYWORDS rfc. (MUST, MUST NOT, SHOULD etc.) https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489.html#section-3